# Why does my program crash when trying to insert a letter after each occurrence of another letter?

Tags: c++, string

This part alone is crashing my program. Why is that? This is to add a 'u' after each 'p' in the string.

```
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
{
    if((s[i]=='p'))
    {
        s.insert(i,1,'u');
    }
}
cout<<"after adding u after each p: "<<s;
```

Comment: Is it your compiler crashing or your program crashing? You realize that  after it adds the 'u', 'p' will be the next thing it finds again.

Comment: well, my program freezes for a few seconds then windows displays that error has occured. CodeBlocks stays open and fully functional, its just the console window that crashes.

Comment: please provide the definition of s as well.

Comment: okay so I take it that your program freezes rather than compiler? I'm guessing you're having access violation at line 3

Comment: @Max..s is a string that is 14 characters long.

Comment: my guess is you have a p as the last character in your string and you're overwriting the '\0' at the end. This would give you an invalid access at line 8.

Comment: @segfault...yeah, the program freezes when I run it. seems like its an infinite loop, but I dont get how is that an infinite loop.

Comment: @Max, `insert` doesn't replace it.

Comment: @MokammelSanju - Look on what chris said in his first comment

Comment: Make it print `s` in every iteration and check.

Comment: @MokammelSanju, You're inserting the u before the p. It then finds p again.

Comment: @Max..no, 'p' is not the last character in my string. my string has 3 more characters after 'p'.

Comment: @chis..yeah, that makes sense because the program crashes like an infinite loop would. But how do I fix it?

Comment: hey guys thanx a lot, I solved it. Apparently @chris was right. The loop was in infinite one because I was adding h before p so it found p again and again (infinte loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(You've written 'u' instead of 'h' in your code.)

Let's assume you have the string that is just "p". So s[0] == 'p'. Now you insert 'h' at 0 so the string is now "hp" (the h is before the p, not after it as you intended). In the next iteration i is 1 and there is a p (it just moved there) so another h will be inserted. This goes on until you run out of memory.

Try:

```
s.insert(i + 1, 1, 'h');
```